# Limpiar un ListBox en tiempo de Ejecución

Tags: c#

Lo que me pasa ahora es que hago un textboxo y un datalist y lo que hago es que se vaya filtrando la lista a medida que escribo a partir de los dos caracteres, pero claro, si borro también se ha de borrar la lista con aquellos resultados que ya no se ajusten a la búsqueda. Pero me da error en como lo hago yo, me da el siguiente error al escribir en la caja de texto a partir de los dos caracteres: 'No se puede modificar la colección Items cuando está establecida la propiedad DataSource.'

Os pego el código para que me enseñéis, por favor:

```
private void TxtBuscar_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string cadena = TxtBuscar.Text;

            if (cadena.Length > 2)
            {
                LstViajes.Items.Clear();
                clases.Viaje objComUsuario = new clases.Viaje();

                Dictionary<int, string> ListaPlantillas = objComUsuario.listadoPlantillas(cadena);

                foreach (var usuario in ListaPlantillas)
                {
                    LstViajes.DataSource = ListaPlantillas.ToList();
                    LstViajes.ValueMember = "Key";
                    LstViajes.DisplayMember = "Value".Trim();
                }

            }
        }
```

Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Básicamente el quiere te dice que si asignas `DataSource` no puedes modificar `Items`.

Entonces deberías modificar la lista que asignas a `DataSource` o no asignar `DataSource` y agregar los elementos manualmente al control por la propiedad `Items`.

Por ejemplo, el primer caso sería el siguiente:

```
// Creas una lista con los elementos 
List<string> elementosMostrados = new List<string>();
// Lista con todos los elementos
List<string> lista = new List<string>();

// Estableces una única vez el DataSource
// Por ejemplo, en el constructor
public Constructor(){
    control.DataSource = elementosMostrados;
}

void cambiarFiltro(string filtro){
    elementosMostrados.Clear();

    // Usando LINQ
    var elementosFiltrados = lista.Where(el => el.StartsWith(filtro));

    // No puedes simplemente asignar la otra lista a la variable
    // elementosMostrados porque estarías trabajando sobre
    // una instancia diferente:
    // elementosMostrados = elementosFiltrados.ToList();
    elementosMostrados.AddRange(elementosFiltrados);
}
```

El segundo caso, asignar los `Items` sería sin `DataSource`, así:

```
// Lista con todos los elementos 
List<string> lista = new List<string>();

void cambiarFiltro(string filtro){
    control.Items.Clear();

    // Usando LINQ
    var elementosFiltrados = lista.Where(el => el.StartsWith(filtro));

    control.Items.AddRange(elementosFiltrados.ToArray());
}
```

Un tercer caso, asignando nuevamente `DataSource` pero sin modificar `Items`:

```
// Creas una lista con los elementos 
List<string> elementosMostrados = new List<string>();
// Lista con todos los elementos 
List<string> lista = new List<string>();

void cambiarFiltro(string filtro){
    // Usando LINQ
    elementosMostrados = lista.Where(el => el.StartsWith(filtro));

    control.DataSource = elementosMostrados;
}
```